# I use Nokia Lumia 730 Dual Sim mobile. And i couldn't sync my contact from my hotmail account.

Tags: sync, contacts, nokia-lumia-730

The sync settings show only email but not contacts option. What can I do to sync my hotmail contacts with my mobile

Comment: Are you sure the contacts aren't actually syncing? Is this the primary MS account on your phone, or a secondary one? Are you running Windows Phone 8.1 or Windows 10 Mobile?

Comment: primary account, I'm using win 8.1 update. but contacts from my secondary account and google account are syncing. its only from primary account I wasn't able to sync.